# THREE.JS Circle floor which will look like shadow

Tags: javascript, three.js, shadow

I need to create a circle mesh with gradient material or something, which will look like it's shadow, so: black in center and almost white on the edge.

Currently I can create a circle and move it on position which it should be:

```
var floorGeometry = new THREE.CircleGeometry((Math.max(loadedObjectRotatedLength.x, loadedObjectRotatedLength.y)/2) + 15, 32);
var floorMaterial = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({color: 0xf0f0f0});

var floor = new THREE.Mesh(floorGeometry, floorMaterial);
floor.position = new THREE.Vector3((loadedObjectBoundingBox.min.x + loadedObjectBoundingBox.max.x)/2, (loadedObjectBoundingBox.min.y + loadedObjectBoundingBox.max.y)/2, loadedObjectBoundingBox.min.z);
```

Anyone can help with creating material which will be like Radial Gradient? :/

Comment: why not just use something like this:
http://209.85.48.18/7059/133/0/p1015675/shadow.png and setting the map to transparent? :)

Comment: I don't know how to map textures in three.js :/

Comment: then see the examples for texture loading on how to do so ;) It's quite easy. Load an image and use it in your materials "map" paramter.

Comment: I tried this and I mapped similar image to this circle and it works :). Thank you for help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a couple of ways of doing it.

**1)** Loading a gradient image and applying it to the material,as mentioned in the comments by @GuyGood

the code will be something like this:

```
    var circleGeometry = new THREE.CircleGeometry(200, 200, 32);
    var texture = THREE.ImageUtils.loadTexture('image/shadow.png');// replace with appropriate URL
    texture.anisotropy = renderer.getMaxAnisotropy();
    var material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({
        map: texture,
        color:0xFFFFFF
    });
    mesh = new THREE.Mesh(circleGeometry, material);
    scene.add(mesh);
```

**2)** The other method I would specially mention here is , we can create a `canvas` element and draw anything on it(in your case it is a circle with gradient on it,but it can be anything), and create a texture of it and apply to the material.

The code will be something like this

```
 var circleGeometry = new THREE.CircleGeometry(100, 100, 100);
    // create a texture on canvas and apply it on material
    var canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
    var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

    var x = 150,
        y = 75,
        // Radii of the black glow.
        innerRadius = 0,
        outerRadius = 200,
        // Radius of the entire circle.
        radius = 200;

    var gradient = ctx.createRadialGradient(x, y, innerRadius, x, y, outerRadius);
    gradient.addColorStop(0, 'black');
    gradient.addColorStop(1, 'white');

    ctx.arc(x, y, radius, 0, 2 * Math.PI);

    ctx.fillStyle = gradient;
    ctx.fill();

    var shadowTexture = new THREE.Texture(canvas);
    shadowTexture.needsUpdate = true;

    var material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({
        map: shadowTexture,
        side: THREE.DoubleSide
    });

    mesh = new THREE.Mesh(circleGeometry, material);
    scene.add(mesh);
```

### [JSfiddle for method 2](http://jsfiddle.net/shivasaxena/6gryajd6/3/)